# Prove uniqueness solution of congruence problem

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that if the set {$n_1,n_2,...,n_k$} is pairwise relatively prime and for all $i$, $0\leq r_i <n_i$ then there is a unique number $s$ with $0\leq s<n_1n_2...n_k$ such that $s\equiv r_i(mod \space n_i)$ for all $i$.

My thought is that we can solve it by induction and it's related to the Chinese remainder theorem but I have no idea how to do it. Can someone please help me? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: This is not related to CRT: it is exactly what CRT says.